# Is there any way to access all of the Clib functions from one file?

Tags: c++, function

I'd like to include just one file instead of all of them, because the compiler I have to use does not include them by default.

Comment: Do you mean by Clib: C standard library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a header that includes all standard headers and include it in your file. That would make compilation slow though.